# Python dictionary in to html table

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Is there any way to print the python dictionary in to a table in HTML. I have a python dictionary and am sending to HTML by using

```
return render_template('index.html',result=result)
```

Now I need to print the elements in result dictionary in to HTML as a table.

Comment: Am using python flask webframe work

Comment: Flask uses Jinja.  Read the manual http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/

Answer (score 53):

Flask uses Jinja as the templating framework. You can just do the following in your template (html)

**Jinja can also be used on its own as a mark-up renderer.**

Python3 / Jinja2

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Key</th>
      <th>Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  {% for key, value in result.items() %}
   <tr>
       <td> {{ key }} </td>
       <td> {{ value }} </td>
   </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Python2 / Jinja

```
<table>
{% for key, value in result.iteritems() %}
   <tr>
        <th> {{ key }} </th>
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: For python3 you would use `result.items()`

Answer (score 7):

Check [Flask-Table](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Flask-Table/0.2.8).

Example from the docs (slightly edited):

```
from flask_table import Table, Col

# Declare your table
class ItemTable(Table):
    name = Col('Name')
    description = Col('Description')

items = [dict(name='Name1', description='Description1'),
         dict(name='Name2', description='Description2'),
         dict(name='Name3', description='Description3')]

# Populate the table
table = ItemTable(items)

# Print the html
print(table.__html__())
# or just {{ table }} from within a Jinja template
```

Answer (score 6):

I've had better luck putting the dictionary into a list of lists, then have the html loop through the list and print the table.
The python would be:

```
Table = []
for key, value in results_dict.iteritems():    # or .items() in Python 3
    temp = []
    temp.extend([key,value])  #Note that this will change depending on the structure of your dictionary
    Table.append(temp)
```

Then in your html you loop through the table.

```
<table>
{% for t in table %}
    <tr>
    {% for i in t %}
        <td>{{ i }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
 </table>
```

Comment: i need to make only certain cells in the table to be editable. And also i would like to add 'datetimepicker.js' module on some cells. Is ther any way?

Comment: So you make the editable cells in the table a text box with the default value of whatever is in the dictionary. You could give the textbox an unique id so datetimepicker could get the cell you want to change.

Answer (score 5):

so I wanted an easy way to generate html from python dictionary with only inline styles (because emails) and couldn't find anything that I was satasfied with so I wrote this,

it's very simple to use and easy to add styles to

```html
<table style="margin: 3px">
    <tr style="background-color: #7cc3a97d">
        <th style="color: white">col1</th>
        <th style="color: white">col2</th>
        <th style="color: white">col3</th>
        <th style="color: white">col4</th>
    </tr>

    <tr style="background-color: aliceblue">
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value11</td>
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value21</td>
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value31</td>
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value41</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: #c2d4e4">
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value12</td>
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value22</td>
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value32</td>
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value42</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: aliceblue">
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value13</td>
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value23</td>
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value33</td>
        <td style="padding: 1rem">value43</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

lets say you have the following dictionary

```
myDict = {
    'col1' : ['value11', 'value12', 'value13'],
    'col2' : ['value21', 'value22', 'value23'],
    'col3' : ['value31', 'value32', 'value33'],
    'col4' : ['value41', 'value42', 'value43'],
}
```

it can be converted with

```
class HTML:

    def __init__(self, Header, tableStyles = {}, trStyles = {}, thStyles = {}):
        self.tableStyles = HTML._styleConverter(tableStyles)
        trStyles = HTML._styleConverter(trStyles)
        thStyles = HTML._styleConverter(thStyles)
        self.rows = []
        self.Header= f'<tr {trStyles} >'
        for th in Header:
            self.Header += f'\n<th {thStyles} >{th}</th>'
        self.Header += '\n</tr>'

    @staticmethod
    def _styleConverter(styleDict : dict):
        if styleDict == {}:
            return ''
        styles = ''
        for [style, value] in styleDict.items():
            styles +=f'{style}: {value};'
        return f'style="{styles}"'

    def addRow(self, row, trStyles = {}, tdStyles = {}):
        trStyles = HTML._styleConverter(trStyles)
        tdStyles = HTML._styleConverter(tdStyles)
        temp_row = f'\n<tr {trStyles} >'
        for td in row:
            temp_row += f'\n<td {tdStyles} >{td}</td>'
        temp_row += '\n</tr>'
        self.rows.append(temp_row)


    def __str__(self):


        return \
f'''
<table {self.tableStyles} >
{self.Header}
{''.join(self.rows)}
</table>
'''



def dictionaryToHTMLTable(dict : dict):
    html = HTML(Header = dict.keys(),
                tableStyles={'margin': '3px'},
                trStyles={'background-color': '#7cc3a97d'},
                thStyles={ 'color': 'white'})
    for i, row in enumerate(zip(*dict.values())):
        print(row)
        if i%2 == 0:
            BGC = 'aliceblue'
        else:
            BGC = '#c2d4e4'
        html.addRow(row, trStyles={'background-color' : BGC}, tdStyles={'padding': '1rem'})
    return html
```

and to output

```
print(dictionaryToHTMLTable(myDict))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, what happens if the dict values lengths are not equal for example {"no_login": ["abc","bcd","cfg"], "no_report": ["1","2","3"], "no_link": ["hello","hii"]}

Comment: @PrarthanRamesh I've ran your example and it works well, you just might want to add some styles inside the function `dictionaryToHTMLTable` to center the text

Comment: thanks, i made some code change to make all the list length are same so that table cell are not showing bit off

Answer (score 3):

For python3, no () after result.items

```
<table>
{% for key, value in result.items %}
   <tr>
        <th> {{ key }} </th>
        <td> {{ value }} </td>
   </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: you need items() not items.

Answer (score 2):

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

tbl_fmt = '''
<table> {}
</table>'''

row_fmt = '''
  <tr>
    <td>{}</td>
    <td>{}</td>
  </tr>'''


def dict_to_html_table(in_dict):
    return tbl_fmt.format(''.join(row_fmt.format(k, v) for k, v in in_dict.items()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    d = {key: value for value, key in enumerate("abcdefg")}
    print(d)
    print(dict_to_html_table(d))
```

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the dictionary items using `result.iteritems()` and then write the keys/data into rows of an html table.

Comment: we have to do result.iteritems in html page?  is there any doc?