# Flask and HTML, from python dictionary to HTML table iteratively

Tags: python, flask

I have a python dictionary of the form

```
data = {
    'category1': {
        'titles': ['t1', 't2', 't3'],
        'dates': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3']
    },
    'category2': {
        'titles': ['t4', 't5', 't6'],
        'dates': ['d4', 'd5', 'd6']
    }
}
```

and I want to create an html table which looks like:

```
category1        category2
t1               t4
d1               d4
--------------------------
t2               t5
d2               d5
--------------------------
t3               t6
d3               d6
--------------------------
```

I am using flask, my flask/python code is:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
import pickle

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    data=pickle.load(open('results.p','rb'))

    return render_template('index.html', x=data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

and my HTML template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>

</head>

<body>

<table>
{% for r,s in x.iteritems() %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ r['titles'] }}{{r['dates']}}</td>
      <td>{{ s['titles'] }} {{s['dates']}}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

However I am getting an internal server error when I run this.

I have also tired `data.iteritems()` without any joy.

I also followed the accepted answer here: [Python dictionary in to html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652325/python-dictionary-in-to-html-table), but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
newdata = zip(
    zip(*(x['titles'] for x in data.values())),
    zip(*(x['dates'] for x in data.values())))

print(list(data.keys()))
for group in newdata:
    for row in group:
        print(row)
    print('-----')
```

Gives you this output:

```
['category1', 'category2']
('t1', 't4')
('d1', 'd4')
-----
('t2', 't5')
('d2', 'd5')
-----
('t3', 't6')
('d3', 'd6')
-----
```

As you can see, the items are now correctly paired in `newdata`. So now you can iterate over it better and produce your table output.

The template code could then look like this:

```
<table>
  {% for group in x %}
     {% for row in group %}
     <tr>
       <td>{{ row[0] }}</td>
       <td>{{ row[1] }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Comment: thanks, so to get this to html via flask would I replace `print(row)` with ` `return render_template('index.html',x=row)` and `<td>{{ r['titles'] }}{{r['dates']}}</td>` in the html file with `<td>{{x}}</td>` ?

Comment: No, you still need to pass the whole `newdata` object and change the loops in the template. I added an example to my answer.

Comment: thanks, there seems to be something else off with my code-- as I am getting the same error. I'll need to keep digging.

Comment: aha, there is a `for` missing in your inner loop!  It totally works now, thanks

Comment: Oh, you’re right! Fixed that, and glad it works now :)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look, I hope that is useful :D

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>My Webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {% for r in x.values() %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ r['titles'] }}{{ r['dates'] }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```